# Referencing unused materials from a JSON scene

Tags: json, three.js, loading, scene

I'm trying to create different materials in a JSON scene, assign a default one to a mesh, and let the user switch between the different materials within the user interface.

Is it possible to reference every materials, even the unused ones, after parsing a JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the code of `THREE.ObjectLoader`, it turns out that it parses the entire JSON but explicitly returns a single reference to the scene object. I solved this issue by monkey patching the `parse` method at runtime. The code is taken from `THREE.ObjectLoader.parse`, only the return value is different (returning an `Object` and not a `THREE.Object3D` anymore).

```
function objectLoaderParseOverride(json, onLoad) {
    var ret = {};

    ret.geometries = this.parseGeometries( json.geometries );
    ret.images = this.parseImages( json.images, function () {
        if ( onLoad !== undefined ) onLoad( ret );
    } );
    ret.textures  = this.parseTextures( json.textures, ret.images );
    ret.materials = this.parseMaterials( json.materials, ret.textures );
    ret.object = this.parseObject( json.object, ret.geometries, ret.materials );
    if ( json.animations ) {
        ret.object.animations = this.parseAnimations( json.animations );
    }
    if ( json.images === undefined || json.images.length === 0 ) {
        if ( onLoad !== undefined ) onLoad( ret );
    }
    return ret;
}

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.parse = objectLoaderParseOverride;
```